# Kendo UI Calendar hightlight specific dates using Ajax

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

My Application is MVC 5; I return list of specific dates using ajax:

```
events = x.Day.Year + ", " + (x.Day.Month -1) + ", " + x.Day.Day
```

I get the correct dates: 2019, 11, 8 .. etc.

The [example I am following](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/calendar/template/) is using an array of dates as follows:

```
var  events = [+new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), 8)];
```

I tried:

```
 success: function (result) {
          if (result && result.events.length > 0) {
                for (var g = 0; g < result.length; g++) {
                    events.push(new Date(result[g].events));
                }
            };
        }
```

Did not work!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your `success` function is incorrectly accessing the `events` array within `result`. **Try updating your `success` function with the snippet below:**

```
success: function (result) {
      if (result && result.events && result.events.length > 0) {
            for (var g = 0; g < result.events.length; g++) {
                events.push(new Date(result.events[g]));
            }
        };
    }
```